# JavaScript Bookmarklet Sends AJAX Request... sometimes?

Tags: javascript, ajax

The idea is to send the current URL via AJAX to a PHP. This works when I put it with button onclick in a <script> tag, but when I add "javascript:(function() { // Code })();" around it and make it a bookmark, it fails to work at all. Here's the code:

```
javascript:(function(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","quickpost?url=" + encodeURI(window.location.href) + "&rand=" +   math.random(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
})();
```

I am bemused and befuddled.

Comment: Maybe it breaks with the quotes inside the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change first letter of the object "Math" it is with big "M"

Comment: Thanks - I've got somewhere, now when I run the code on this page I get an alert, but it alerts the source code of this page. When I run it on Google it doesn't do anything...

Comment: That is because you can't do cross-domain requests (its disabled for security reasons).
You can search for "how to cross domain request ajax" for solusion.